# Create unicode character with pack

Tags: perl, unicode

I am trying to understand how Perl handles unicode.

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

use Encode qw(encode);

say unpack "H*", pack("U", 0xff);
say unpack "H*", encode( 'UTF-8', chr 0xff );
```

Output:

```
ff
c3bf
```

Why do I get `ff` and not `c3bf` when using pack ?

Comment: `pack('U', 0xFF)` is a weird way of doing `chr(0xFF)`, so it's no surprise that it's different than `encode('UTF-8', chr(0xFF))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do I get ff and not c3bf when using pack ?

This is because pack creates a character string, not a byte string.

```
> perl -MDevel::Peek -e 'Dump(pack("U", 0xff));'
SV = PV(0x13a6d18) at 0x13d2ce8
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADTMP,POK,READONLY,pPOK,UTF8)
  PV = 0xa6d298 "\303\277"\0 [UTF8 "\x{ff}"]
  CUR = 2
  LEN = 32
```

Hence unpack("H*") doesn't look at the byte-value of that string, but the (truncated) character value of it. If you'd do:

```
say unpack "H*", encode("UTF-8", pack("U", 0xff));
```

Then you'd get the expected result.

See also [this thread](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2013/05/msg201247.html).

Comment: Ok so unpack can only handle byte strings (not character strings). It would be interesting to know how it truncates when it is given a character string, and where this truncation of character strings are documented?

Comment: unpack H* apparently does a module 256 on the values, I don't think this is documented. Generally speaking, you shouldn't throw any character string at it, that will only cause grief.

Comment: @Leon Timmermans, "This is because it creates character string, not a byte string." is complete nonsense, and there's truncation or modulo 256 happening here. He did `unpack("H*", "\xFF")`, which is perfectly legitimate.

Comment: @ikegami: that wasn't always so, on older versions of perl that returns `c3bf`

Comment: @Leon Timmermans, Yeah, `pack`'s handling of some scalars used to be super buggy. I think it was fixed in 5.10. I don't know why you brought this up since noone's talking about the buggy behaviour of decade-old versions of Perl.

Answer (score 2):

```
pack('U', 0xFF)
```

is just a weird way of doing

```
chr(0xFF)
```

so

```
"\xFF"                             returns chars   FF
chr(0xFF)                          returns chars   FF
pack('U', 0xFF)                    returns chars   FF

"\xC3\xBF"                         returns chars   C3 BF
encode('UTF-8', chr(0xFF))         returns chars   C3 BF
encode('UTF-8', pack('U', 0xFF))   returns chars   C3 BF
```

so

```
say unpack "H*", "\xFF";                             outputs   ff
say unpack "H*", chr(0xFF);                          outputs   ff
say unpack "H*", pack('U', 0xFF);                    outputs   ff

say unpack "H*", "\xC3\xBF";                         outputs   c3bf
say unpack "H*", encode('UTF-8', pack('U', 0xFF));   outputs   c3bf
say unpack "H*", encode('UTF-8', chr(0xFF));         outputs   c3bf
```

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure I understand.  Why is then `perl -MDevel::Peek -e 'Dump(pack 'U', 0xff);'` returning `c3bf`, whereas `perl -MDevel::Peek -e 'Dump(chr 0xff);'` returns `ff` ? (You say that they both should return `ff`..)

Comment: `perl -MDevel::Peek -e 'Dump(pack 'U', 0xff);'` says the string is `"\x{ff}"`. `perl -MDevel::Peek -e 'Dump(chr 0xff);'` says the string is `"\377"`. In both cases, that's the single character `FF`. They are stored in differently internally, but they are the same thing string just like signed integer zero and floating point zero are both zero.

Comment: If code looks sees `C3 BF` when looking at `pack 'U', 0xff`, it's buggy. To work with such buggy code, you can use `utf8::upgrade` and `utf8::downgrade` to switch a variable between the two storage formats.

Comment: If I run `perl -MDevel::Peek -e 'Dump(pack 'U', 0xff);`, I get `PV = "\303\277"\0 [UTF8 "\x{ff}"]`. What do you get?

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, The same: The string `"\x{ff}"` stored using the UTF8=1 storage format

Comment: And then `perl -MDevel::Peek -e 'Dump(chr 0xff);'` gives me `PV = "\377"\0`. So what confuses me is that obiviously "\377" is not the same as "\303\277". (But in your answer you say that `pack('U', 0xFF)` is the same as `chr 0xff`)

Comment: Noone said "\377" is the same as "\303\277". I said `chr(0xFF)` is the same as `pack('U', 0xFF)`, and neither are "\303\277". You're confusing yourself by using the wrong tool. I already told you a convenient tool for examining strings: `sprint '%vX'`. Try `say chr(0xFF) eq pack('U', 0xFF) ? "equal" : "not equal";` Not only will that say equal, you'll find they have the same length (1), and each of the characters are identical (`ord` returns 0xFF for the first and only character).

Comment: Why do people understand that IV="\0\0\0\1" [+1] and NV="\0\0\0\0\0\0\360\77" [+1.0*2^0] are the same number, but they refuse to accept that PV="\377"\0 ["\x{ff}"] and PV,UTF8="\303\277"\0 ["\x{ff}"] are the same string?!? Why do those same people insist on peeking at the internal storage???